# Is there a way to Reflect JavaScript properties and method from a "class" or function, not from an object?

Tags: javascript, reflection

It's very easy to get reflection from a JavaScript object, just as following code.

```
var getAllMembers = function (obj) {
    var members = {};
    members.properties = [];
    members.methods = [];

    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] != 'function')
            members.properties.push(prop);
        else members.methods.push(prop);
    }
    return members;
}

function demo_class(na, nb) {
    this.a = na;
    this.b = nb;

    this.funca = function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
    this.funcb = function () {
        console.log(this.b);
    }
}

var x = new demo_class(1234, 4321);

var members = getAllMembers(x);

console.log(members.properties);  // [ 'a', 'b' ]
console.log(members.methods);     // [ 'funca', 'funcb' ]
```

My question is: Is there a way to get properties and methods from a class or function, instead of from an object? For example, like this:

```
var members = getAllMembers(demo_class); // Only can get '[] []'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript there is no real concept of class, because it is a prototypal language. A function is an object.

What you can do is test if your object has a named function constructor, to test if it is an object contructed with a function or not. If not, you can create an instance to get the properties like you already did:

NOTES: this will work only if you use class constructors defined with the keyword function (not constructed via another named function). Your function will also get all the inherited properties from the prototype chain, if you don't use the `hasOwnProperty()` function.

```
var getAllMembers = function (obj) {
    var members = {}, toTest;
    members.properties = [];
    members.methods = [];

    //construct object if argument is a constructor
    toTest = (obj.constructor === Function) ? new obj() : obj;

    for (var prop in toTest) {
        if (typeof toTest[prop] != 'function')
            members.properties.push(prop);
        else members.methods.push(prop);
    }
    return members;
}

function demo_class(na, nb) {
    this.a = na;
    this.b = nb;

    this.funca = function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
    this.funcb = function () {
        console.log(this.b);
    }
}

var x = new demo_class(1234, 4321);

var members = getAllMembers(x);

console.log(members.properties);  // [ 'a', 'b' ]
console.log(members.methods);     // [ 'funca', 'funcb' ]

var members = getAllMembers(demo_class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript everything is an object. It doesn't exists the class concept. So each time you use the new operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) it returns you an object using the function as a constructor.

You can get an approximation to this using the Prototype concept. Where you define your methods in the prototype instead of the constructor function itself.

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
    return this.name + " " + this.family;
};
```

Here is a post explaining it https://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/methods-within-constructor-vs-prototype-in-javascript/